# text() in Processing

Tags: java, graphics, fonts, processing, lag

I'm playing around with Processing to see how everything works, but when dealing with the text() method, it seems to be having load time issues.

The code I have simple loads a PNG image onto the screen, followed by 3 4 letters words of size 24. When I leave only the image loading code in there, the application starts straight away, but when I put the text() code in, it takes approximately 3-4 seconds before it loads.

The above was done straight from Processing application, but I'm actually developing it inside a JFrame, so for the first 4 seconds, I actually see a blank JFrame which is quite ugly.

My question to you guys is whether any of you are aware of an issue with text(), or if there is a logical reason as to why it takes so long to load up.

--Running Java 7 on a Quad core machine

## Here's the relevant code

```
PImage backgroundImage;
PFont font;

/**
 * PApplet method - performs all setup actions
 */
public void setup(){
    this.size( 1400, 900);
    
    backgroundImage = loadImage( "EG_dark.png" );
    backgroundImage.resize( width, height );
    this.background(backgroundImage);
    
     font = createFont("AmericanTypewriter", 24);
     textFont(font);
    
}

/**
 * PApplet method - All drawing occurs here
 */
public void draw(){
    if(backgroundImage.width != width || backgroundImage.height != height){
        backgroundImage.resize( width, height );
    }
    
    this.background(backgroundImage);

    fill(0, 102, 153);
    text("word", 15, 30); 
    fill(0, 102, 153);
    text("word", 15, 60);
    fill(0, 102, 153);
    text("word", 15, 90);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are describing is the proper behavior of processings createFont.

To cite straight from the documentation:

> createFont():
>
> Dynamically converts a font to the format used by Processing from
> either a font name that's installed on the computer, or from a .ttf or
> .otf file inside the sketches "data" folder. This function is an
> advanced feature for precise control. On most occasions you should
> create fonts through selecting "Create Font..." from the Tools menu.

what you are trying to do is better handled by creating the vlw font file through the processing application: menu/tools/Create Font... (copy resulting file into data folder of your app)

```
PFont font;
font = loadFont("AmericanTypewriter.vlw");
textFont(font, 24); 
...
text("word", 15, 50);
```